# Magento 2.3 error after cache flush or clean

Tags: magento2, cache

Every time I flush or clean Magento cache I get the following error on front and backend:

> Exception: Notice: Undefined variable: _ENV in /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Processor/EnvironmentPlaceholder.php on line 57 in /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61 Stack trace: #0 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Processor/EnvironmentPlaceholder.php(57): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined varia...', '/home/jacstoreo...', 57, Array) #1 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/PreProcessorComposite.php(35): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Processor\EnvironmentPlaceholder->process(Array) #2 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader.php(60): Magento\Framework\App\Config\PreProcessorComposite->process(Array) #3 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/generated/code/Magento/Config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader->read() #4 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(326): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader\Proxy->read() #5 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(218): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->readData() #6 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(168): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->loadDefaultScopeData('default') #7 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(142): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->getWithParts('default/web/url...') #8 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(131): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get('default/web/url...') #9 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(80): Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('system', 'default/web/url...') #10 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/MutableScopeConfig.php(36): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('web/url/use_sto...', 'default', NULL) #11 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Request/StorePathInfoValidator.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\MutableScopeConfig->getValue('web/url/use_sto...') #12 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php(99): Magento\Store\App\Request\StorePathInfoValidator->getValidStoreCode(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #13 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php(157): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->getCurrentStoreId() #14 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/generated/code/Magento/Store/Model/StoreManagerInterface/Proxy.php(119): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager->getStore(NULL) #15 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Resolver/Store.php(30): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface\Proxy->getStore(NULL) #16 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ScopeCodeResolver.php(49): Magento\Store\Model\Resolver\Store->getScope(NULL) #17 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeCodeResolver->resolve('stores', NULL) #18 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/Logger/Handler/Debug.php(63): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('dev/debug/debug...', 'stores') #19 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(31): Magento\Developer\Model\Logger\Handler\Debug->isHandling(Array) #20 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(344): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array) #21 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Logger/Monolog.php(48): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, 'Notice: Undefin...', Array) #22 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(707): Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog->addRecord(400, 'Notice: Undefin...', Array) #23 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263): Monolog\Logger->error('Notice: Undefin...') #24 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor)) #25 {main}